# Cucumber: Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

i am using **cucumber** for testing the scenario. I am getting error as:

> > Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)

when using `diff!` in my code.

```
Then /^the results should be:$/ do |expected_results|
results = [['content']] + page.all('ol.results li').map do |li|
[li.text]
end 
expected_results.diff!(results)
end
```

I had also refer most of the site related these issue, as using `transpose` before `diff!` method i was wasn’t success. Also, i had followed https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/220 , but got no effect on this error. Can anyone define me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have done this already, but it looks like you are using the progress formatter which doesn't give any helpful details about table difference errors.

If you use the pretty formatter using the `--format pretty` flag, cucumber should print out the full details of the table difference.

Comment: Not sure if this was downvoted by the OP? @devilsmind could you add the output of --format pretty so we can see the actual difference between the tables? Alternatively add the results of expected_results.to_s

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by out-of-sequence rows (according to [The Cucumber docs](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/ruby/yardoc/Cucumber/Ast/Table.html#diff!-instance_method), out-of-sequence columns are handled gracefully, but out-of-order rows apparently aren't).

In my case, I got this working by using an explicit ORDER BY in my SQL statement and re-ordering the rows in my expected table.